# nidaqmx installation in Jupyter and spyder

Tags: installation, jupyter, spyder, nidaqmx

I am trying to install nidaqmx in Jupyter and spyder. It seems that it does not work. there is no output of the simple example to get a voltage value in Jupyter. In IDLE the same simple code works.

%pip install nidaqmx

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: nidaqmx in c:\users\daquser\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.22 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nidaqmx) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: deprecation>=2.1 in c:\users\daquser\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from nidaqmx) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from deprecation>=2.1->nidaqmx) (22.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed socket <zmq.Socket(zmq.PUSH) at 0x23add55e860>
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils_process_win32.py:124: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=3>
return process_handler(cmd, _system_body)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils_process_win32.py:124: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=4>
return process_handler(cmd, _system_body)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils_process_win32.py:124: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=5>
return process_handler(cmd, _system_body)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback